# Serie from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, dotnethighcharts

I am trying to store values from specific column from SQL Server Database to `List<Serie>`

I am using dotNet Highcharts.

Below is my code. It is having some issue.

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=INBDQ2WK2LBCD2S\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MCAS;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select top(100) x from Table4 order by Id desc", cnn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Table4");

    List<Serie> xValues = new List<Serie>();

    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["Table4"].Rows)
    {
        xValues.Add(row["x"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: "It is having some issue." isn't very specific. Do you get error message(s)? If so, please add details. Does it load no/fewer than expected rows? What does the data in `Table4` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to retrieve the data is perfectly fine. However, you are making the error when adding it to the list.

You want to store data in a `List<Serie>`. Now we do not know what type of object `Serie` is, nor what properties it does have. But you try to add a string to your list.

There are 2 ways of resolving this:

Change the type of your list to `List<String> xValues = new List<String>();`

or

Change your `xValues.Add()` line to something which adds a valid object of type `Serie`.

```
//you need to check Serie constructors to see which properties need to passed.
xValues.Add(new Serie(row["x"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you to open connection before accessing DB data and closed after access data.

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=INBDQ2WK2LBCD2S\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MCAS;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
{
    cnn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select top(100) x from Table4 order by Id desc", cnn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Table4");
    cnn.Close();
    List<String> xValues = new List<String>();

    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["Table4"].Rows)
    {
        xValues.Add(row["x"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: [`DataAdapter.Fill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/377a8x4t(v=vs.110).aspx): "The connection object associated with the SELECT statement must be valid, but it does not need to be open. If the connection is closed before Fill is called, it is opened to retrieve data, then closed"